# How to display data from JSON into html table

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, reactjs

[image: Everything is good i just need those marked names in each row to ne in a column under schoolClassName]I was trying to display json data into html table , schoolClasseName to be table header(th) and students(student firstName) which belongs to particular schoolClass to be in a column under table header - schoolClassName.

```
showGrades = (myJson) => {
    console.log(myJson);
    var cardContainer = document.getElementById('card-holder');
    console.log(cardContainer)
    cardContainer.style.display = "none";
    var contentSection = document.getElementById("content-section");
    console.log(contentSection)
    var para = document.createElement("div");
    para.className += "studentsFromDb";
    contentSection.appendChild(para);
    var t = "";
    myJson.forEach(element => {

        var container = "<div>"
        container += "<h1> Grade Number" + element.gradeNumber + "</h1>"
        container += "<table><tr>" + element.schoolClasses.map((el) => {
                return "<th>" + el.schoolClassName + "</th>"
            }) + "</tr>" + element.schoolClasses.map((el) => {

                return el.students.map((el) => {
                    return "<td>" + el.firstName + "</td>"
                    })
            }) + "</table>"

        container += "</div>";
        t += container;
    });
    para.innerHTML += t;             
}


My JSon file:
[
    {
        "schoolClasses": [
            {
                "students": [
                    {                           
                        "firstName": "Svetislav"
                   },
                    {                            
                        "firstName": "Gavrilo"
                    },
                    {                            
                        "firstName": "Milos"
                    },
                    {                            
                        "firstName": "Marko"
                    }
                ],
                "id": 1,
                "schoolClassName": "fifthThree",
                "gradeId": 1
            },
            {
                "students": [
                    {                                                        
                        "firstName": "Mladen"
                    },
                    {
                        "firstName": "Zoran"
                    },
                    {
                        "firstName": "Boban"                           
                    },
                    {
                        "firstName": "Goran"
                    }
                ],
                "id": 2,
                "schoolClassName": "fifthOne",
                "gradeId": 1
            },
            {
                "students": [
                    {
                        "firstName": "Milovan"
                    },
                    {
                        "firstName": "Jorgovan"                            
                    },
                    {                           
                        "firstName": "Jovan"

                    }
                ],
                "id": 3,
                "schoolClassName": "fifthTwo",
                "gradeId": 1
            }
        ],

        "id": 1,
        "gradeNumber": 5
    },

grade 6
    {
        "schoolClasses": [
            {
                "students": [
                    {                           
                        "firstName": "Branimir"
                    },
                    {
                       "firstName": "Stanislava"
                    },
                    {                           
                        "firstName": "Zorana"
                    },
                    {                           
                        "firstName": "Zvezdana"
                    }
                ],
                "id": 4,
                "schoolClassName": "sixthOne",
                "gradeId": 2
            },
            {
                "students": [
                    {                            
                        "firstName": "Dragana"                            
                    },
                    {                         
                        "firstName": "Ivana"                           
                    },
                    {

                        "firstName": "Mirjana"
                    },
                    {

                        "firstName": "Milica"

                    }
                ],
                "id": 5,
                "schoolClassName": "sixthTwo",
                "gradeId": 2
            },
            {
                "students": [
                    {

                        "firstName": "Marijana"
                    },
                    {

                        "firstName": "Dobrila"
                    },
                    {

                        "firstName": "Marija"
                    },
                    {

                        "firstName": "Dobrila"

                    }
                ],
                "id": 6,
                "schoolClassName": "sixthThree",
                "gradeId": 2
            },
            {
                "students": [
                    {

                        "firstName": "Svetislava"
                    },
                    {

                        "firstName": "Milica"
                    },
                    {

                        "firstName": "Zlatija"
                    },
                    {

                        "firstName": "Serafina"                       
                    }
                ],
                "id": 7,
                "schoolClassName": "sixthFour",
                "gradeId": 2
            }
        ],
        "id": 2,
        "gradeNumber": 6
    }
]
```

I have 3 `th` but i have more data and it goes like this

```
FirstSchoolClass SecondSchoolClass ThirdSchoolClass 
Michael          Stefany           Monica          Stephan Mike Taylor etc ..
```

I need after 3 `td` to build new `tr` with 3 `td`.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Could you elaborate more on what the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood your issue correctly, the issue is that the code was only creating one row and appending many `td` cells, and you need each of the `student` arrays to be in a new row.

You just need to add opening `tr` before you map the inner `schoolClasses` and closing `tr` after.  I also added `.join('')` to remove commas `,` that were being appended to the HTML. (I also named the json array `"grades"` to make the json valid in this example).

See the snippet below.

```js
showGrades = (myJson) => {
    var cardContainer = document.getElementById('card-holder');
    cardContainer.style.display = "none";
    var contentSection = document.getElementById("content-section");
    var para = document.createElement("div");
    para.className += "studentsFromDb";
    contentSection.appendChild(para);
    var t = "";
    myJson["grades"].forEach(element => {
        var container = "<div>";
        container += "<h1> Grade Number" + element.gradeNumber + "</h1>";
        container += "<table><tr>" + element.schoolClasses.map((el) => 
            {
                return "<th>" + el.schoolClassName + "</th>"
            }).join('') + "</tr><tr>" + element.schoolClasses.map((el) => 
            {  // added tr here  ^^    
                return el.students.map((el) => 
                {
                    return "<td>" + el.firstName + "</td>"
                }).join('') + "</tr>"; // added join('') and '</tr>'            
            }).join('') + "</table>";  // added join('')

            container += "</div>";
            t += container;
        });
        para.innerHTML += t;             
    }

var json = {
     "grades": [{
        "schoolClasses": [{
            "students": [
                   {
                        "firstName": "Svetislav"
                   }, {
                        "firstName": "Gavrilo"
                    }, {
                        "firstName": "Milos"
                    }, {
                        "firstName": "Marko"
                    }
                ],
                "id": 1,
                "schoolClassName": "fifthThree",
                "gradeId": 1
            }, {
                "students": [
                    {
                        "firstName": "Mladen"
                    }, {
                        "firstName": "Zoran"
                    }, {
                        "firstName": "Boban"
                    }, {
                        "firstName": "Goran"
                    }
                ],
                "id": 2,
                "schoolClassName": "fifthOne",
                "gradeId": 1
            }, {
                "students": [{
                        "firstName": "Milovan"
                    }, {
                        "firstName": "Jorgovan"
                    }, {
                        "firstName": "Jovan"
                    }
                ],
                "id": 3,
                "schoolClassName": "fifthTwo",
                "gradeId": 1
            }
        ],

        "id": 1,
        "gradeNumber": 5
    }, {
        "schoolClasses": [{
                "students": [{
                        "firstName": "Branimir"
                    }, {
                        "firstName": "Stanislava"
                    }, {
                        "firstName": "Zorana"
                    }, {
                        "firstName": "Zvezdana"
                    }
                ],
                "id": 4,
                "schoolClassName": "sixthOne",
                "gradeId": 2
            }, {
                "students": [{
                        "firstName": "Dragana"
                    }, {
                        "firstName": "Ivana"
                    }, {

                        "firstName": "Mirjana"
                    }, {
                        "firstName": "Milica"
                    }
                ],
                "id": 5,
                "schoolClassName": "sixthTwo",
                "gradeId": 2
            }, {
                "students": [{
                        "firstName": "Marijana"
                    }, {
                        "firstName": "Dobrila"
                    }, {
                        "firstName": "Marija"
                    }, {
                        "firstName": "Dobrila"
                    }
                ],
                "id": 6,
                "schoolClassName": "sixthThree",
                "gradeId": 2
            }, {
                "students": [{
                        "firstName": "Svetislava"
                    }, {
                        "firstName": "Milica"
                    }, {
                        "firstName": "Zlatija"
                    }, {
                        "firstName": "Serafina"
                    }
                ],
                "id": 7,
                "schoolClassName": "sixthFour",
                "gradeId": 2
         }
      ],
      "id": 2,
      "gradeNumber": 6
    }
  ]
}

// run code
showGrades(json);
```

```html
<div id="content-section"></div>
<div id="card-holder"></div>
```

Comment: wait please, names in a row need to be in a column under SchoolClass Name, for example in fifthThree goes : Svetislav, Gavrilo, Milos, Marko..

Comment: i post picture for more help

Comment: The problem is the json structure. You're trying to fit 4 names into 3 columns. You'd need an extra "fifthFour" section to do that. Does the json need to be in that format?

Comment: Yes thats format, i can not edit json,do you have any suggestion how to display students with grades and school classes it doesnt needto be in a table.

Comment: i just need Grade Number  under that schoolClass Name and under that students that belong to that school Class, i hope that you understand main goal.

Comment: i got what i want with tr with names display flex, flex-direction:column , but that is not the best solution .